# How to create numpy array from dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dataframe

I am working with a `Pandas` DataFrame that contains 4 columns: 'TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper' and 'Sales'. I need to create two `NumPy` arrays: `X` that contains the first 3 columns and `y` that contains the 'Sales' column.
I figured out there are two ways to create a `NumPy` array from a `Pandas` DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array(adver_data.iloc[:,0:3].values)
y = np.array(adver_data["Sales"].values)
```

and:

```
import numpy as np
X = adver_data[['TV', 'Radio', 'Newspaper']].values
y = adver_data[['Sales']].values
```

The problem is that even though these two ways actually create a `NumPy` array later my code gives different results for these two ways and I don't know why as I don't see how the arrays of the two ways are different.

What is the difference?

Comment: if they gives you the same numpy array then maybe problem is in other code.

Comment: **Note:** Per [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) `.to_numpy()` should be used rather than `.values`.

Comment: Giving a sample data set, your output and expected output will help in better understanding your problem and answer your question much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have '`n`' rows of data.

The code:

```
y = np.array(adver_data["Sales"].values)
```

gives shape of `y` as `(n,)` i.e. **1D array**

whereas the code:

```
y = adver_data[['Sales']].values
```

gives shape of `y` as `(n, 1)` i.e. **2D array**

So, you are getting different results.

Comment: That's true, but you failed to insist on the underlying reason. In first code you convert a Series which gives a 1D array, in second one you convert a DataFrame which gives a 2D array.